# How to make bond lines thicker with Rdkit

Tags: python, matplotlib, rdkit

I am using RDkit to draw a molecule in 2D. I am trying to use `DrawingOptions.bondLineWidth` to control the bond thickness but it doesn't seem to be working (the bond lines remain the same thickness regardless of the value I set it to). Any idea?

```
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import DrawingOptions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

DrawingOptions.atomLabelFontSize = 55
DrawingOptions.dotsPerAngstrom = 100
DrawingOptions.bondLineWidth = 10.0

mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('CC(C)(C)c1cc(O)ccc1O')
img = Draw.MolToImage(mol, size=(1000, 1000), fitImage=True, kekulize=False, fitWidth=True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(img)
ax.grid(False)
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It SHOULD be the same thing, but I suggest you remove your second import and just do `Draw.DrawingOptions.bondLineWidth`.

Answer (score 3):

I found out [here](https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/issues/2496#issuecomment-714512724) that `DrawingOptions` is deprecated and ignored by `MolToImage` in favour of `MolDrawOptions`. I updated the code, this is working with `rdkit==2022.9.4`

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

opts = Draw.MolDrawOptions()
opts.bondLineWidth = 5.

mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('CC(C)(C)c1cc(O)ccc1O')
img = Draw.MolToImage(mol, size=(500, 500), options=opts)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(img)
ax.grid(False)
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```